# How to add horizontal line over grid

Tags: html, css

> Hi I want to add horizontal line over the grid.
>
> My requirement is this.

[image]

This is 4 column bootstrap grid.

But i am getting this.

[image]

My HTML code is bellow.

```
 <div class="row">
 <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;margin-left:0">
    <spam style="border-bottom: solid 1px #DEDEDE"></spam>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 collapsible">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wc-footer">

        <ul class="footer links">
                <li style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 700; padding-bottom: 20px;"><b><?php echo  __('About us')?></b></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('cart')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('favorate product')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('About the Group')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Business and financial reports')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Strategy')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Imprint')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Cookie statement')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Privacy Policy<')?>/a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Terms of sale via online store')?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wc-footer">
        <ul class="footer links">
                <li style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 700; padding-bottom: 20px; "><b><?php echo  __('Quick Links') ?></b></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Imprint')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Cookie statement')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('Privacy Policy')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><?php echo __('BTerms of sale via online store')?></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    
</div>

</div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wc-footer">
        <ul class="footer links">
                <li style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 700; padding-bottom: 20px; "><b><?php echo __('Pratite nas')?></b></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 20px;"><a href="" ><img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/facebook.png'); ?>'  style="margin-right:30px; display: inline-block;
                    vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo __('Facebook')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 20px;"><a href="" ><img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/linkedin.png'); ?>'  style="margin-right:20px; display: inline-block;
                    vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo __('Linkedin')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 20px;"><a href="" ><img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/youtube.png'); ?>'  style="margin-right:15px; display: inline-block;
                    vertical-align: middle;"> <?php echo __('YouTube')?></a></li>
                <li class="nav item" href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><a href="" ><img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/instagram.png'); ?>'  style="margin-right:15px; display: inline-block;
                    vertical-align: middle;"> <?php echo __('Instagram')?></a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wc-footer">
    <ul class="footer links">
                <li style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 700; padding-bottom: 20px;"><b><?php echo __('Kontakt')?></b></li>
                <hr>
                <li style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400;"><div><?php echo __('For offers or inquiries call our toll-free number 0800 4260.')?></div></li>
                
                <li style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom: 20px;"><div><?php echo __('MON - FRI from 08:00 - 16:00')?></div></li>

                
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I want know how can i add horizontal  line over the box.
Basically i want a overly layer of horizontal line over the grid.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it will look great on mobile, but on desktop the HR isn't going all the way across like pointed out.

The problem is that the approach to fix this would be to have all your headers in one row with four columns, have a row for the HR, then a row with four columns for the list items. The problem is that on mobile, the headers will be separated from your list items because it'll render all four headers, the HR, then all four lists.

I think a possible fix is to style the HR so that it is full width, then give it negative margins to span the gaps between columns. Something like this:

```
<hr style="width: calc(100% + 30px); margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;">
```

Consider not putting the HR tag in the middle of your UL tag. Your headers can use `<h2>` and start the `<ul>` after, like this:

```
<h2><?php echo __('Pratite nas')?></h2>
<hr style="width: calc(100% + 30px); margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;">
<ul class="footer links">
    <li ...
```

Also, when you decide what the styles will look like, you can move your CSS from the style tags to CSS classes. That'll make your code easier to maintain.